# failed to create client: parse "http://127.0.0.1:8200": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon in Hashi-corp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am getting below error when executing the following commands from ***windows*** using **Hashi-Corp vault**.

> failed to create client: parse "http://127.0.0.1:8200": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon

```
C:\Softwares\vault_1.0.1_windows_amd64>set VAULT_TOKEN="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

C:\Softwares\vault_1.0.1_windows_amd64>set VAULT_ADDR="http://127.0.0.1:8200"

C:\Softwares\vault_1.0.1_windows_amd64>vault auth enable approle
failed to create client: parse "http://127.0.0.1:8200": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
```

If I don't set the environemnt variables, then I get the below error.

```
C:\Softwares\vault_1.0.1_windows_amd64>vault auth enable approle
Error enabling approle auth: Post https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/auth/approle: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using below - Don't use "".

```
set VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this in windows , (in command prompt) ,

SET VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

SET VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200

vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config example.username=hello example.password=world

Answer (score 3):

I wondered, why the above answers did not work for me, because I was using powershell.

**PowerShell:**

```
$env:VAULT_ADDR="http://127.0.0.1:8200"

$env:VAULT_TOKEN="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

**cmd.exe:**

```
set VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200

set VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```